# validation error by using react-phone-input-2 value with react-hook-form in react

Tags: reactjs, validation, input, react-hook-form

There is an input created by using react-phone-input-2. To validate it  I use  react-hook-form. When sending an empty form, validation occurs. But when I try to enter numbers into the form, an error appears in the console "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')".
I think is looking for target.name, but react-phone-input-2 immediately gives out a value, no target. I thought that the <Сomponent> could solve this problem, but it does not help.

```
import PhoneInput from "react-phone-input-2";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { ErrorMessage } from "@hookform/error-message";

const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
 };

  const {
    field,
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      name: "",
      tel: "",
    },
    criteriaMode: "all",
  });
```

And Form

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <div className={styles.form_tel}>
        <label className={styles.label_tel} htmlFor="phone">
          {labelTel}
        </label>

        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="tel"
          render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
            <PhoneInput
              {...field}
              id="phone"
              country="ru"
              name="tel"
              {...register("value", {
                required: "The field is required",
              })}
              inputProps={{ ref, required: true }}
              specialLabel={null}
            />
          )}
        />
        <ErrorMessage
          errors={errors}
          name="name"
          render={({ messages }) => {
            console.log("messages", messages);
            return messages ? Object.entries(messages).map(([type, message]) => <p key={type}>{message}</p>) : null;
          }}
        />
      </div>

      <button className={styles.callToAction_btn} type="submit">
        {submitBtnText}
      </button>
    </form>
```

I have looked at articles on these topics and similar issues, but their solutions do not help me